# How do I achieve the same result as Thread.Sleep() but async, and preserve the same behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, console

I have the following `C#` console program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Flood
{
    class Program
    {
        private static List<DateTime> CommandsList = new List<DateTime>();
        private static double SecondsPassed = 0;

        public static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Invoke Control method
                Control(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        private static void Control(string command)
        {
            // Calculate total seconds passed since first entry of the list until now
            if (CommandsList.Count != 0)
                SecondsPassed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(CommandsList[0]).TotalSeconds;

            // If less than 10 seconds passed
            if (SecondsPassed < 10)
            {
                // If list contains more than 2 entries
                if (CommandsList.Count >= 2)
                {
                    // Wait for the amount of time left to complete 10 seconds, then clear the list
                    Thread.Sleep((10 - Convert.ToInt32(SecondsPassed)) * 1000);
                    CommandsList.Clear();
                }
            }

            // If more than 10 seconds passed, clear the list
            else
                CommandsList.Clear();

            // Add current time to list
            CommandsList.Add(DateTime.Now);

            // Repeat the command to the user
            Console.WriteLine("You typed: " + command);
        }
    }
}
```

It does exactly what I expect it to do. Basically, if a user quickly inserts 6 lines, numbers 1 through 6, it outputs this:

```
1
You typed: 1
2
You typed: 2
3
[Wait ~10 seconds]
You typed: 3
4
You typed: 4
5
[Wait ~10 seconds]
You typed: 5
6
You typed: 6
```

However, there's an obvious problem: since I'm using `Thread.Sleep()`, the user can't even see their input after the first 3 lines.

I'd like to do this asynchronously so that the user sees all their inputs, but I want to keep the behavor intact. Meaning, the output should send 2 entries at a time, every ~10 seconds.

I tried using `await Task.Delay()` and converting the method to `async`, but even though the user now sees their input, the console outputs this:

```
1
You typed: 1
2
You typed: 2
3
4
5
6
[Wait ~10 seconds]
You typed: 3
You typed: 6
You typed: 4
You typed: 5
```

So it waits for ~10 seconds, then writes all the inputs right away. I'd like it to wait ~10 seconds between every 2 entries.

Any ideas to achieve this?

Comment: A `BlockingCollection` with a separate thread polling it every 10 seconds may be worth considering.

Comment: The title of your question does not in any useful way describe the question itself. Taking the title literally, `Task.Delay()` is what you want. However, you say you've already tried that and it doesn't accomplish what you want. So you _don't_ actually want _"Thread.Sleep() but async"_. It's likely that you actually have a multi-part question here, where you need help with several different aspects. That would be too broad in any case, but it would be very good if you would pick _one_ aspect, ask about that, get that working, and then move on to the next part in a different question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The question of the title doesn't encompass the whole problem, but the body does. I'm not even sure how I'd divide this in multiple questions and get something working first, because of what I describe in the body.

Comment: I don't understand the body. It's not at all clear what you want to do. The closest you come to an explanation is _"It does exactly what I expect it to do...However, there's an obvious problem"_. You know what you expect it to do, but you haven't bothered to share that with the rest of us, and knowing that there's a problem that's obvious to you, doesn't in any way help elucidate the question. The first comment above suggests a .NET type that is commonly used to implement producer/consumer scenarios, so if that's what you're trying to do, maybe you should start there.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I not explain the problem? Right after what you quote: "Basically, if a user quickly inserts 6 lines, numbers 1 through 6, it outputs this:", then I show the output, then explain the problem: "However, there's an obvious problem: since I'm using Thread.Sleep(), the user can't even see their input after the first 3 lines." I'll take a look at the first comment.

Comment: `Sorry, but how do I not explain the problem?` My tip to you is that whenever someone says you have not explained a problem well, **strongly** resist the temptation to defend yourself. It doesn't matter whether the problem is clear to **you**. It matters whether it is clear **to the reader**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I think @mjwills gave you a good hint with the first comment (assuming I understood the question correctly). Have one thread read the inputs and push them to a `BlockingCollection`. Have the other iterate on the BlockingCollection and wait 10 seconds every 2 entries

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem screams for the producer-consumer pattern: a producer produces input in  a different speed than a consumer consumes the input: sometime faster than the consumer, sometimes slower than the consumer.

For this you'll use [nuget package Microsoft TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow)

In essence, you have one or more Producer blocks, which produce data and put it in a Buffer. One or more Consumer blocks wait until data arrives at the buffer, and process it. If desired the Consumer can Produce the processed data and put it in another buffer, where other Consumers are listening.

If a Producer is finished Producing data, he notifies the buffer. All Consumers of the buffer know that no data is to be expected anymore and if they are also Producers they notify their output buffer that nothing is to be expected anymore.

**The Producer** reads the user input, until the user notifies to stop (empty line). All input is sent to the buffer, without waiting (Post). The Producer will read the next line immediately.

```
class UserInputProducer
{
    // Reads user input until user enters empty line
    // User input is sent to output buffer
    public async Task ProduceAsync()
    {
         string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
         while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
         {
             // send the user input to the output buffer
             this.producedUserInput.Post(userInput);
             userInput = Console.ReadLine();
         }

         // no more inpu expected:
         this.ProducedUserInput.Complete();
    }

    public ITargetBlock<string> ProducedUserInput {get; set;} = DataflowBlock<string>.NullTarget;
}
```

The ProducedUserInput is initialized with the NullTarget. As long as this is not changed, then apparently no one is interested in my produced output.

**The Consumer** will wait for input strings and process it.

I'm not sure what you wanted to do with the commandsList. Therefore I'll make the consumer a bit more interesting. For this example the Consumer has two outputs: one with the string "You typed ..." and one with the DateTimes that you used to put in CommandsList. So in fact, this Consumer is also a Producer.

```
class CommandProcessor
{
    public IDataFlowBlock<string> Source {get; } = new BufferBlock<string>();

    public ITargetBlock<string> YouTypedTarget<string> {get; set;} = DataFlowBlock.NullTarget<string>;
    public ITargetBlock<DateTime> CommandTimeTarget {get; set;} = DataFlowBlock.NullTarget<DateTime>;

    public async Task ProcessInput()
    {
        // wait for source output available:
        while (await this.Source.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
             // fetch the input and the time that this input was received;
             string dataToProcess = await this.Source.ReceiveAsync();
             DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow;

             // process the output to the two Destinations
             this.YouTypedTarget.Post("You typed "+ dataToProcess);
             this.CommandTimeTarget.Post(time);
        }

        // if here: no data to produce anymore
        this.YouTypedTarget.Complete();
        this.CommandTimeTarget.Complete();
    }
}
```

You need two Consumers: one for the YouTyped output, and one for the CommandTime. I'll give one:

```
class YouTypedConsumer
{
    public IDataFlowBlock<string> Source {get; } = new BufferBlock<string>();

    public async Task ConsumeAsync()
    {
        // wait for source output available:
        while (await this.Source.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
             // fetch the input and display it on the console
             string txtToDisplay= await this.Source.ReceiveAsync();
             Console.WriteLine(txtToDisplay);

             // this Consumer does not produce anything
        }
    }
}
```

The CommandTimeConsumer is similar.

Tie it all together:

```
var youTypedConsumer = new YouTypedConsumer();
var conmmandTimeConsumer = new CommandTimeConsumer();

// youTypedTarget of the command processor is input youTypedConsumer
var commandProcessor = new CommandProcessor
{
    YouTypedTarget = youTypedConsumer.Source,
    CommandTimeTarget = commandTimeConsumer.Source,
}

var userInputProducer = new UserInputProducer
{
    ProducedUserInput = commandProcessor.Source,
};
```

So the userInputProducer sends its produced data to the Source of the commandProcessor. The commandProcessor processes the input, and sends the result to the source of the youTypedConsumer and to the source of the commandTimeConsumer.

Now start everything async and await until all tasks are completed:

```
var tasks = new Task[]
{
    youTypedConsumer.ConsumeAsync(),
    commandTimeConsumer.ConsumeAsync(),

    commandProcessor.ProcessAsync(),
    userInputProducer.ProduceAsync(),
};

// await until all tasks are finished:
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// or if this procedure is not async:
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

The nice thing is that every block has a small task. Easy to understand the task. Easy to reuse for other configurations, like a unit test. No problem if any of the producers or consumers are sometimes bit slower or faster then the one block before or after it. And it is fully async.

Comment: The [Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow) package is deprecated. The maintained is the [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/).

Comment: Also the `OutputAvailableAsync` should be used in pair with the [`TryReceive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.tryreceive). The pair `OutputAvailableAsync`+`ReceiveAsync` introduces a race condition.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for all the explanation! I'll go through the code, experiment with it, and try to implement it.